# Custom Item Frame Paintings

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I really have to make an item frame painting, take a screenshot, and post it to Imgur and Pinterest. Is there a way to make an item frame painting did in the following image (Of course there is)?
[image: Build Battle Custom Painting]

Answer (score 0):

The real solution: Build with colored blocks in a big area and make in-game maps of that area.

A better solution for you: Make a screenshot of an empty wall and then use an image editing program to put the image in that place.